# How do I repeat an Azure Logic App Action 50 times?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

I have an Azure Logic App with multiple HTTP actions calling various endpoints within a web application of mine. Please excuse the basic question, but is there a way to repeat one of the HTTP actions 50 times for example, passing the current index to the request as part of the query string?

Take the below example. I'd like to repeat HTTP 2 action 50 times.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a Do Until Loop that checks and increments a variable.

[Create loops that repeat workflow actions or process arrays in Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-loops)

In fact, the Do Until section is exactly what you're looking for.